# WP-Admin gives 403 Forbidden after login on CentOS 7

Tags: customization, vps

I've setup a brand new CentOS 7 VPS; everything configured by me. LAMP installation and the Apache virtual host configurations are all done. I've checked them before installing Wordpress and the HTML sites were being showed as well as the PHP info and everything else.

After that I went on to setup Wordpress as usual. Then I tried to log-in(the log-in page got loaded successfully) but the log-in page directed me to an error message of `403 Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/ on this server.`

What seems to be the issue? I've a separate user than `root` managing the VPS whom also has root privileges and it also has ownership on the Wordpress files. Also the files and folder all have 755 as their permissions. Is this a `.htaccess` issue?

A detailed explanation would be much appreciated. Thanks.

P.S. Also my firewall is not yet installed

Comment: Remove `.htaccess` and try accessing website again.

Comment: @Nick I haven't defined any .htaccess files. Should I go look out for any other defined by some system processes.

Comment: WordPress creates it automatically. It must be in root folder.

Comment: @Nick Yup, there was one there. But it was empty. Anyway, I deleted it, restarted Apache and nothing changed unfortunately. :(

Comment: I added a code below in answer. Paste this in your .htaccess file. Make sure you use `nano` or `vi` on server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this in your .htaccess file at website root folder.
If you deleted it then create it again and paste this.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

### EDIT

Looks like you have issue with `DirectoryIndex`.
In your `httpd.conf` search for `DirectoryIndex` and make sure you add index.php in it.
Or in your virtual host configuration.

Like this.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
```

Comment: Seen it before. Tried it again with no luck. This problem is really bugging me. Thanks.

Comment: Try one more thing. Open `www.yourdomain.com/index.php` in browser and see if it redirects to `www.yourdomain.com/` or you get 403 error on `www.yourdomain.com/index.php` page itself.

Comment: Gave an error of 403 again.

Comment: Did you read my comment correctly? It will give 403 error but what is the URL now. Is it `www.yourdomain.com/index.php` or `www.yourdomain.com/`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. It's `www.yourdomain.com/`

Comment: Then WordPress is working fine and you need to set directory's default index file with DirectoryIndex. I edited the answer with more info.

Comment: Finally. Yes. You made my day Sir. Thanks a bunch. :)

Comment: Glad you got it working. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had two directory callouts to the same directory. one was placed in the regular httpd.conf file and the other was in my virtual host conf. As soon as I deleted the one in the regular conf, my virtual host wp-admin began working.